# Having trouble with baking textures on an image

Tags: uv, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I am relatively new to UV unwrapping and baking textures, I am trying to bake the colour(diffuse) of different objects that make up a CRT monitor model I made onto an Image("Baking"), I first added in the shader editor a image texture node not plugged in to anything that linked to the image I intended to bake the textures on and highlighted did this to every object in the model, then I made sure all of the objects had their metallic value to 0, then I went over to the object data properties tab to add UV maps to each objects "Baking" and highlighted it for every object, then I went into edit mode to select all of them and smart uv unwrap them onto the Baking Image, I then entered the render properties tab to change to Cycles and scrolled down to the Bake tab, under 'Influence' I unselected Direct and Indirect and left Color selected, Bake type was set to Diffuse, I click Bake and, the result is that some of the objects texture get messed up and turn black or the UV unwrapping is wrong, any help? Thanks.[image: Before baking]
[image: Before baking]
[image: After baking Notice some objects have their texture messed up or blacked out]

Here is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/f8ada16603874ebd9b31fa297bf8c12d

Comment: If you share the file, it would be useful

Comment: Okay, just edited it, you should be able to see the file.